# iOS Black keyboard

Tags: ios, user-expectation, guidelines, keyboard

Is the black iOS keyboard used to indicate that the form is secure?

There seems to be suggestions that it is the case but I can not find a clear answer within any guidelines and have seen the black keyboard used within apps.

Tia,
Simon

Answer (score 2):

I have done some research, but I haven't found a clear answer.

My answer for this question is:
For the apple guidelines the black keyboard is not used for indicate a secure form.

> iOS, being a privacy- and security-first operating system, does place
>   some limitations on custom keyboards. First, by default they have to
>   keep everything local to the device. That's to prevent key-logging
>   activity. (Where a malicious app steals what you're typing.) If the
>   keyboard does want to add server-side intelligence (which can improve
>   the system), it has to ask your express permission. Apple will then
>   warn you about the app having access to your credit card or street
>   address information, but let you go ahead if you choose to.
>
> What's more, whenever you move to a secure password field, third party
>   keyboards are temporarily disabled and the standard iOS 8 keyboard is
>   presented instead. This is not only to prevent key-loggers, but to
>   prevent anyone at all from having any access to your passwords
>   whatsoever.
>
> Apple will no doubt also provide appropriate toggles in the Settings
>   app should we wish to change our minds later.